# How to use Distiller joboptions in pdfTeX?

Tags: pdftex

I've always used `.tex`-> `.dvi` -> .`ps` -> PDF workflow for PDF creation. Now I want to switch to direct .`tex` -> PDF creation using pdfTeX engine (LuaLaTeX, ConTeXt or pdfLaTeX). But I have a strict requirements for `pdf - .joboption`, which I use with Distiller.
Does any body wrote Distiller `joboptions` aliases for pdfTeX?
How it should be done?
For example, I see `joboptions`:

```
<<
  /ASCII85EncodePages false
  /AllowTransparency false
  /AutoPositionEPSFiles true
  /AutoRotatePages /None
...
...
>>
```

All these "tasks" (`/foo`) has to be written with `\pdfliteral`, like:
`/ASCII85EncodePages false` --> `\pdfliteral {<code to set ASCII85EncodePages to false>}`

Is it even possible?

Comment: You can't: Distiller job options are for Distiller. You can post-process your PDF from pdfLaTeX with Adobe's tools, but that's off-topic for us.

Comment: Why do you give those options? Perhaps the direct LaTeX ~~-> PDF trip gives you what you want already, or with some options to pdflatex or to the packages you are using?

Comment: Vonbrand, options I wrote are just an example. I'm pretty shore that pdftex does lots of that job automatically, but I don't now how to test wich of the joboptions are done.

Comment: @Linas: pdfTeX does not handle _any_ Distiller joboptions (as it is not a PostScript distiller). [What problem do you want to solve](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2449/5763)?

Comment: Martin, now I understood that. As I wrote in a main post, I want to switch to pdflatex. But I need to be shore, that it passes the distiller .joboptions, because publisher uses thees .joboptions to check pdf. So, I think I need to write a special tex styles where I would program something for different types of pdf.

Comment: I've found some hints in http://support.river-valley.com/wiki/index.php?title=Generating_PDF/A_compliant_PDFs_from_pdftex. Now I'll need to pick all the errors and find a solutions how to fix them :)

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the Distiller job options, whether you can go the direct route via pdfTeX. At least the shown options seem not to pose a problem:

```
/ASCII85EncodePages false
```

pdfTeX compresses the pages with /FlateEncode. (Compression can be turned off via `\pdfcompresslevel=0`.) /ASCII85Encode is not used for page streams.

```
/AllowTransparency false
```

Unless you are using a package that enables/uses transparency, transparency
is not used by pdfTeX itself.

```
/AutoPositionEPSFiles true
```

Not relevant. Images in LaTeX are usually embedded with packages `graphics`/`graphicx`/`pdfpages`.

```
/AutoRotatePages /None
```

pdfTeX does not have a "auto-rotating" feature.

But there are options that will not work with pdfTeX.